# C++11 Allocator default interfaces I have to provide

Tags: c++11, memory-management, allocator

When creating my own allocator in c++11 I am implementing the following interfaces. This works with vector but when trying to use this with map I get errors on missing items. I thought this was all I need to implement for c++11 since it will use allocator_traits in the stl implementations. What am I missing here? Do I need to define more methods / data structures for an allocator for std::map?  I am seeing the following errors when trying to compile currently (see below). Line 3 main.cpp is just

```
#include <map>

template <class T> struct MyAllocator {
    typedef T value_type;
    MyAllocator() noexcept;  // only required if used
    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator&) noexcept;  // copies must be equal
    MyAllocator(MyAllocator&&) noexcept;  // not needed if copy ctor is good enough
    template <class U> MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<U>& u) noexcept; 
        // requires: *this == MyAllocator(u)
    value_type* allocate(std::size_t);
    void deallocate(value_type*, std::size_t) noexcept;
};

template <class T, class U> bool
operator==(const MyAllocator<T>&, const MyAllocator<U>&) noexcept;
```

Errors:

> In file included from
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/map:61:0,
>   from main.cpp:3:
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_map.h: In
>   instantiation of ‘class std::map,
>   MyAlloc >’:
>   main.cpp:146:14:   required from here
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_map.h:143:58:
>   error: no type named ‘pointer’ in ‘std::map,
>   MyAlloc >::_Pair_alloc_type {aka class
>   MyAlloc, 200   typedef typename
>   _Pair_alloc_type::pointer         pointer;                                                                                                                                                                         ^
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_map.h:144:58:
>   error: no type named ‘const_pointer’ in ‘std::map, MyAlloc >::_Pair_alloc_type {aka class
>   MyAlloc
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_map.h:145:58:
>   error: no type named ‘reference’ in ‘std::map, MyAlloc >::_Pair_alloc_type {aka class
>   MyAlloc, 2  typedef typename
>   _Pair_alloc_type::reference       reference;                                                                                                                                                                      ^
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_map.h:146:58:
>   error: no type named ‘const_reference’ in ‘std::map, MyAlloc >::_Pair_alloc_type {aka class
>   MyAlloc
>   In file included from
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/map:60:0,
>   from main.cpp:3:
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_tree.h: In
>   instantiation of ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue,
>   _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_t  /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_tree.h:1124:23:
>   required from ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_tree.h:671:28:
>   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::~_Rb_tree() [with _Key = int; _Val = std::pair; _KeyOfValue = std::
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_map.h:96:11:
>   required from here
>   /opt/gcc-4.8.1/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_tree.h:421:2:
>   error: ‘std::_Rb_tree,
>   std::_Select1st >, std::less,
>   MyAlloc, 200ul> >:
>   _M_get_Node_allocator().destroy(__p);                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
>   make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: note this works after adding construct, destroy and some type defs for pointer etc. It's just that in all the literature I didn't think I needed these.

Comment: some of your lines are unduly long

Comment: Could you please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This will make it ease for people to help you. [Ideone](http://ideone.com) is a useful tool to showcase the compilation errors with less clutter.

Comment: It is likely that gcc-4.8.1 simply does not yet implement the full C++11 spec in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically as my comment suggested I needed to put the typedefs for the following and a construct and destroy

```
        template <class U> 
        struct rebind {typedef MyAlloc<U, N> other;};  

        typedef size_t size_type;                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef T* pointer;
        typedef const T* const_pointer;
        typedef T& reference;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        typedef const T& const_reference;                                                                                                                                                                                              
        typedef T value_type;          

       /// Call constructor with many arguments                                                                                                                                                                                       
        template<typename U, typename... Args>                                                                                                                                                                                         
        void construct(U* p, Args&&... args)                                                                                                                                                                                           
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            // Placement new                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            ::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);                                                                                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        /// Call destructor                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        template<typename U>                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        void destroy(U* p)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            p->~U();                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        }
```

Comment: How odd. According to "The C++ Standard Library
A Tutorial and Reference" by Nicolai M. Josuttis (2nd Edition), pg 1026 "You don’t have to provide construct() or destroy(), because their default implementations usually work fine". Before that he said that you have to provide the/a: (1) definition of value_type (2)  constructor (3) template constructor (4) member functions allocate() and deallocate() (5) if necessary, constructors and a destructor (6) operators == and !=. "For the rest, appropriate defaults are usually provided."

Answer (score 1):

The first errors are solved using some typedefs within MyAllocator:

```cxx
typedef T& reference;
typedef const T& const_reference;
typedef T* pointer;
typedef const T* const_pointer;
```

Please post your new compilation output.